# How do I store axios response so that I can use it in different functions

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a nodejs project and I need to store the response data of this axios request

```
    let px2resp;
    
    async function sendPx2() {
        try {
            let data = await axios.post('https://collector-pxajdckzhd.px-cloud.net/api/v2/collector', qs.stringify(PX2data), {
                headers: PX2headers
            });
            px2resp = data;
            return px2resp;
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
      

  }
}
```

the way that I'm doing it right now is

```
let testing = async () => {
    var a = await sendPx2();
    console.log(a)
}
testing();
```

But the issue with this is that it makes the request everytime I want to use the data which is no ideal. Is there anyway for me to store this response data and use it without having to make the request multiple times?

Comment: you can use some shared service, or can also write the response to the local file. Later, you can check for the value or file content in the test method.

Comment: Will the data expire at any time, so you should re-fetch again to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you don't want to store data in a file)

This may be the approach you are looking for:

```js
let px2resp;
let alreadyFetched = false;
let cachedData = null;

async function sendPx2() {
  // check if data was fetch already (to avoid same request multiple times)
  // if so, return previous fetched data
  if (alreadyFetched) return cachedData;

  // else fetch data
  let data = await axios.post(
    'https://collector-pxajdckzhd.px-cloud.net/api/v2/collector',
    qs.stringify(PX2data),
    {
      headers: PX2headers,
    }
  ).catch((e) => console.log(e)); // This is optional (use try/catch if you still want)

  // set variables
  alreadyFetched = true;
  cachedData = data;

  return data;
}
```

And you can still use your existing code as normal but this time it will not fetch the data everytime if it was already fetched before.

```js
let testing = async () => {
    var a = await sendPx2();
    console.log(a)
}
testing();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data inside a JSON file... Using the writeFile function in Node JS :)

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('helloworld.json', px2resp, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Data Written');
});
```

Then read it from the file to use in the Functions.

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('helloworld.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

Make sure to add `utf-8`, so it will not return Buffer Data.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data on a file

```
var fs = require("fs");
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

const expiry = 10*60*1000 // 10 minutes


function cachedFunction(fn){
  return async (...params) => {
    let path = `${fn.name}:${params.join(":")}.json` 
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
      let rawdata = await readFile(path, 'utf-8');
      let response = JSON.parse(rawdata.toString());
      console.log(response)
      if(response.created_at + expiry > Date.now()){
        console.log("getting from cache")
        return rawdata
      }
    }
    const data = await fn(...params) 


    if(data && typeof data === 'object'){
      const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify({...data,created_at: Date.now()}) 
      fs.writeFileSync(path, stringifiedData);
    }
    return data
  }
}

async function hello(){
  return {a:1,b:2}
}


async function test() {

  console.log(await cachedFunction(hello)("x"))
  
}
test()
```